# Open Google Drive website when authenticated with Google Service Account

Tags: asp.net, session, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I have a ASP.NET Web Application successfully integrated with GSUITE.
Using a Service Account, the users are allowed to view their files inside of my application.
I implemented it using the .NET Google API v3.
However, i have a customer request to also have a link to drive.google.com, opening in a new tab of the browser with his session already open.
Opening drive.google.com do not have a session and still asking for the username and password, and we need them authenticated. It make sense because in any moment i created a session in the client side with Google Drive.

I tried to read Google documentation and on StackOverflow but nothing seems to have a answer for it.
I was thinking about retrieve the user credentials and try to create a session but i am not sure how to do it...

Is it possible?